# How to change react-vitualized Grid and List default static classname

Tags: reactjs, list, grid, react-virtualized

Is there a way I can change the default static classname for List and/or Grid?

className="sample-classname" just appends to the current classsname :(

here is my sample code

```js
<WindowScroller>
  {({ height, width, isScrolling, onChildScroll, scrollTop }) => (
    <List
      className="sample-classname"
      ref={setRef}
      autoHeight
      height={height}
      width={1140}
      isScrolling={isScrolling}
      onScroll={onChildScroll}
      rowCount={data.size}
      rowHeight={this.rowHeight}
      rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
      scrollTop={scrollTop}
      overscanRowCount={1}
    />
  )}
</WindowScroller>
```

Comment: It's hard-coded https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/List/List.js#L192 . What's the problem with it? This may be XY problem.

Comment: actually there are no problem with that, I just want to have it customized how it looks like in developer console :D

Comment: You can apply any additional class or style to it that will override styles from default class, I guess.